# how to add second range label with AndroidPlot (2 series, same range values)

Tags: android, androidplot

So I have a graph which uses 2 series. Both are within same range.

First serie has a lot of data and produces the overall graph. Second is just a horizontal line showing at the right edge of the graph what the latest value is.

It looks like this

[image]

My questions are :

1. how to add range label for this horizontal dashed line? so that it shows only with latest value on the right.

One solution that I am aware of, is to overlay two plot views per series but I would prefer not to.

2. How to add range label so that it is always shown next to dashed line? (single value)

cheers

Answer (score 0):

There is unfortunately no easy way to do this without customizing the source of XYGraphWidget; lines, points and their labels are all drawn within the GraphWidget's grid region, which is clipped at its edges. Domain and range labels exist outside of this region.

If you can live with the label appearing somewhere within the grid region then you can use PointLabeler and PointFormatter to annotate your line.  You might also consider replacing your horizontal dashed line series with a YValueMarker.

Another option is to use a TextLabelWidget to display your value in a static location outside the grid.